# Iterating over two lists and resulting in a third one

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

Does anyone know how would be a iteration code to do this:

I give two initial lists (`l1` and `l2`):

```
l1=[a,b,c], where a,b,c are numbers
l2=[i,j,k,w,z]
```

And then get a third one (`l3`; which has the same length of `l1`):

```
l3=[[a*i+a*j+a*k+a*w+a*z],[b*i+b*j+b*k+b*w+b*z],[c*i+c*j+c*k+c*w+c*z]]
```

Comment: Hint: `a*i+a*j+a*k+a*w+a*z` is equal to `a*(i+j+k+w+z)`, which is equal to `a*sum(l2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l3 = []
for i in l1:
    temp = 0
    for j in l2:
        temp += i*j
    l3.append([temp])
```

But of course, there's a one-liner for that:

```
l3 = [[sum(i*j) for j in l2] for i in l1]
```

But with some algebra:

```
total = sum(l2)
l3 = [[i*total] for i in l1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The one-liner should look this way:

```
l3 = [[sum([i*j for j in l2])] for i in l1]
```

inspectorG4dget will return list of lists of numbers.
But then again, his algebra solution will work and is the best one :)